# Express Routing for requests that may match 2 endpoints

Tags: node.js, express

I have the below 2 Endpoints

/a/:b

/a/tags

When a request is made
with path  /a/1           -  I need to route it to /a/:b
with path /a/tags       - I need to route to /a/tags.

How do I make this happen? Currently when a request /a/tags is made, it gets routed to /a/:b (the Endpoint with path parameter). Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance

NOTE: We are building an app that can accept any Open API Specs (Swagger) and build a mock app based on endpoints in Swagger. The Swagger specs may have 2 or more endpoints(one with path parameter and another without path parameter but having a similar path) that could match a given request. I am looking for a generic solution to resolve the route.

Thanks in Advance

I have reviewed the https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html but not able to find an answer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to set the least specific route last, as express will run the first foute that matches, in your case you should swap the a/tags route and the a/:b route.